# How to add attributes {{var}} inside {{#each}}?

Tags: jquery, html, handlebars.js

I would like to know if there's any way to add double-stashed {{var}} embeds to my HTML.

For example:
I have the .hbs code here:

```
{{#each tables.books.data}}
<tr>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

And my .js code:

```
$(tableID+">tbody>tr").attr("tabindex", "{{@key}}");
```

what I want for it to look like on the web is this:

```
<tr tabindex="1">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr tabindex="2">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr tabindex="3">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
...
```

But currently I'm experiencing:

```
<tr tabindex="{{@key}}">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr tabindex="{{@key}}">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr tabindex="{{@key}}">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
...
```

Is there any other way or functions to render double-stashed {{var}} embeds?
Just to recap, my objective is whenever the page loads add `attribute={{@key}}` in `<tr>`.
I also don't intend installing other packages but if that's the only way, then okay.

Answer (score -2):

Handlebars is a templating language, which means that Javascript can't fully interact with it because Handlebars is rendered on the server side and Javascript is executed on the client side - the template (or an API) is literally the communication medium between the two. Furthermore, the Javascript will also just read `"{{@key}}"` as a string literal, not as the handlebars variable you're thinking of. If you want Handlebars to print the key into the template, you have to add it into the hbs template itself:

```
<tr tabindex="{{@key}}">
```

If you absolutely must have it in Javascript, you can pass it through in something like a data attribute:

```
// in .hbs file
<tr data-tabindex="{{@key}}">

// in js
tr = $('tr')[0] // grab a <tr> element
tr.data('tabindex') // should be whatever value was in @key
```

Comment: Okay thanks but I don't *need* it to pass from the .hbs file to .js
what I need is to add `{{@key}}` as attribute from `.js` to `<tr>` in my .hbs file.
So whenever I enter a page with a table, all of its `<tr>` will have rendered `tabindex={{@key}}`.

Comment: That's what I'm saying, `{{@key}}` is from handlebars, not Javascript. Search `@key` on this page: https://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html

Comment: You can't add it from Javascript if it doesn't exist in Javascript to begin with

Comment: Meaning, if I have 5 .hbs files with tables I have to put `<tr data-tabindex="{{@key}}">` on each of it?

Comment: Yes. Javascript doesn't have any idea what `{{@key}}` is. You could use JS to iterate over any other kind of collection, but your client side javascript will for sure will never know what `{{@key}}` is unless you specifically tell it what it is.

Comment: My current reputation is 32, and it takes 125 reputation to down vote, so, technically it's not me. Thanks for the intense explanation @Brian Kung.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173439/discussion-between-brian-kung-and-quer).

Comment: @BrianKung Handlebar isn't designed to be rendered on a server you can render it on the client and have nothing to do in the server.